# Rails 4 to heroku font issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts

I've successfully uploaded my rails app to heroku, the fonts aren't working can anyone give me step by step instructions as to how to fix this problem?

In `app/assets/stylesheets`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya_sans';
    src: url('/assets/alegreyasanssc-thin.eot');
    src: url('/assets/alegreyasanssc-thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/alegreyasanssc-thin.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/alegreyasanssc-thin.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/alegreyasanssc-thin.svg#alegreya_sans_scthin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'latobold';
    src: url('/assets/lato-bold.eot');
    src: url('/assets/lato-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/lato-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/lato-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/lato-bold.svg#latobold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/assets/opensans-regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/opensans-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/opensans-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/opensans-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/opensans-regular.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I have a .fonts directory in the root of my app, I've precompiled by running `rake assets:precompile`, and yet I still get a 404 error what's the problem? When I check `heroku logs` I'm getting a routing error

Comment: If you really need help you should spend more time writing a question. We are not wizards to know what the problem is from a single-line question.

Comment: Try this `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Thanks **Sharvy Ahmed** that seemed to get rid of the 404 error but I still can't seem to get the fonts to work

Comment: If you goto www.yourdomain.com/assets/alegreyasanssc-thin.eot do you get the font file?

Comment: No I get `The page you are looking for doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the links in your CSS files aren't going to the right place to load the fonts. You should move your 'fonts' folder to be within:

```
/assets/fonts/
```

Then you need to change the css file to:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya_sans';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/alegreyasanssc-thin.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/alegreyasanssc-thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/alegreyasanssc-thin.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/alegreyasanssc-thin.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/alegreyasanssc-thin.svg#alegreya_sans_scthin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'latobold';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/lato-bold.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/lato-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/lato-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/lato-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/lato-bold.svg#latobold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/opensans-regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/opensans-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/opensans-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/opensans-regular.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: That didn't work and already had the fonts directory in the assets directory all I did was add `fonts/` to the url it didn't work